# Using RedirectView and ClientHttpRequestInterceptor Together

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redirect

I am currently using the RedirectView to perform a redirect during an authentication flow in my application. I am looking to intercept any/all redirects occurring in my application by using ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.

However, while this works for all REST GETs/POSTs from my app, the redirect is not intercepted by ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.

Is there a different interceptor that I am unaware of that would be able to do this? Or, is there a way to do a redirect differently which would get picked up by ClientHttpRequestInterceptor?

Comment: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-handler-interceptor.html